# Build fails when building Cordova project on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, cordova, azure-devops

While trying to `build` Cordova project for Android, the build is failing with an ERROR as follows:

> d:\a_tasks\CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7\1.3.11\lib\cordova-task.js:70
>       process.chdir(cwd);
>               ^ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir

[image]

Can anyone let me know how to resolve this error?

The log file says:

```
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7209717Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Cordova Build android'
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7209717Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7209717Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7209717Z ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7209717Z ##[debug]Expanded: True
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7209717Z ##[debug]Result: True
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7209717Z ##[section]Starting: Cordova Build android
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7509720Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7509720Z Task         : Cordova Build
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7509720Z Description  : Build a hybrid app project based on the Cordova CLI, Ionic CLI, TACO CLI, or other Cordova-compliant CLI
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7509720Z Version      : 1.3.11
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7509720Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7509720Z Help         : [More Information](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=691186)
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7509720Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-01T09:58:52.7679724Z ##[debug]tf vc resolvePath "$\VisitReport_Br\Client Components\Main\Source\visitreportpoc_client with windows and android working\visitreportpoc.sln" /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2017-11-01T09:58:53.3029712Z ##[debug]d:\a\1\s\Client Components\Main\Source\visitreportpoc_client with windows and android working\visitreportpoc.sln
2017-11-01T09:58:55.1959726Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=d:\a
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ANTBUILD
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CONFIGURATION
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CORDOVAVERSION
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CWD
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_IOSSIGNMETHOD
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_KEYSTOREFILE
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_OUTPUTPATTERN
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_P12
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PLATFORM
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PROVPROFILE
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_REMOVEPROFILE
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TARGETEMULATOR
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_UNLOCKDEFAULTKEYCHAIN
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WINDOWSONLY
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WINDOWSPHONEONLY
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]loaded 18
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]BUILD_SOURCEDIRECTORY=undefined
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2239725Z ##[debug]BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY=d:\a\1\s
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]CWD=d:\a\1\s\Client Components\Main\Source\visitreportpoc_client with windows and android working\visitreportpoc.sln
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]XCODEDEVELOPERDIR=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]CONFIGURATION=Debug
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]ARCHS=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]PLATFORM=android
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]TARGETEMULATOR=false
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]WINDOWSAPPX=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]WINDOWSONLY=false
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]WINDOWSPHONEONLY=false
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]UNLOCKDEFAULTKEYCHAIN=false
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]DEFAULTKEYCHAINPASSWORD=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]P12=d:\a\1\s
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]P12PWD=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]IOSSIGNINGIDENTITY=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]PROVPROFILEUUID=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]PROVPROFILE=d:\a\1\s
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]REMOVEPROFILE=false
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]ANTBUILD=false
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]KEYSTOREFILE=d:\a\1\s
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]KEYSTOREPASS=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]KEYSTOREALIAS=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]KEYPASS=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]OUTPUTPATTERN=bin
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]CORDOVAARGS=null
2017-11-01T09:58:55.2249717Z ##[debug]CORDOVAVERSION=6.2.1
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7119726Z d:\a\_tasks\CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7\1.3.11\lib\cordova-task.js:70
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7119726Z     process.chdir(cwd);
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7119726Z             ^
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7119726Z 
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7119726Z Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7119726Z     at Error (native)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7119726Z     at processInputs (d:\a\_tasks\CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7\1.3.11\lib\cordova-task.js:70:13)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7119726Z     at Object.<anonymous> (d:\a\_tasks\CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7\1.3.11\lib\cordova-task.js:32:1)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7119726Z     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7129723Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7129723Z     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7129723Z     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7189705Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7189705Z     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7189705Z     at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7309743Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7399729Z ##[error]Task failed
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7399729Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Task failed
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7419727Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Task failed
2017-11-01T09:58:56.7479948Z ##[section]Finishing: Cordova Build android
```

The detailed log of get source is uploaded to the link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw3JaIcGOgq7TFd2UHN5bHJ5TkE/view?usp=sharing

The zip file of detailed log after all changes is :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw3JaIcGOgq7VWxWSDJLYUVZUjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What if you queue the build with private agent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Nope, my number of builds have exhausted so will have to wait for a week and try the workaround and check if it solves my problem

Comment: No i did not get a solution to this issue yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified an Working Directory that isn’t existing on build agent, verify it:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the Working directory still the problem persists!

Comment: @KrishnaLahoti What's the working directory you specified? Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive (Set System.debug to true, then queue build)?

Comment: @KrishnaLahoti What's the working directory you specified? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: the working directory is same as where i have my solution file of the project,  the issue is not solved yet

Comment: I have updated the question with the content of log file

Comment: Provide the detail log of get sources.

Comment: The detailed log of get sources contain more than 76k lines

Comment: However i have uploaded the log file of Get source and the link is mentioned in the above question description.

Comment: @KrishnaLahoti Based on the log, the working directory is `d:\a\1\s\Client Components\Main\Source\visitreportpoc_client with windows and android working\visitreportpoc.sln`, it is a file path instead of folder path, just use `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\Client Components\Main\Source\visitreportpoc_client with windows and android working`

Comment: tried with the above path still same problem, no effect

Comment: Provide the detail log here.

Comment: I have shared the link of detailed zip file of the complete log in the question of the build that i generated using above recent change suggested

Comment: @KrishnaLahoti You need to set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the log.

Comment: I did the same, i had set the system.variable to true and then shared the log

Comment: There isn't the debug information in the log, try to delete the old shared files, then share the new log files.

Comment: Anyways i solved the problem, i will post the answer to help others facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In the working directory of Cordova Build i mistakenly selected the .sln file instead of the working directory itself. After changing the path from .sln file to my working folder that contains the .sln file the build completed successfully.

[Here's the screenshot of the same:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi8Yc.png)